# Marking, annotating and commenting parts of photography collaboratively

Tags: web-apps, photography, collaboration

When I review my photographs I like to mark on the photography (with a circle, square or freeline) and comment a part of a photography I would improve, e.g. "this ear should be hidden", or "there is no light in the eye, another source of light would help here".

Is there a Web application that would allow me to comment and colloborate with other people in this way? This would allow me to receive feedback from other in a way that is more precise than pure comments.

I could self-host it for myself if needed. No price limit for now.

Comment: You might be able to do this simply by converting the photo into a single-paged google doc which you then share to whoever you want, and they can edit it collectively and simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [InVision](https://www.invisionapp.com/)?

- it's a hosted web app,
- once signed up, you can choose the "Freehands" option where you upload the picture you want to work on, make marks and comments and, if you share the link to what you are working on with anyone via email, they can leave their comments and marks as well,
- from what I've seen, all of this can be done in the free tier but if you need more, you can always check out the premium options.

Maybe worth a look.